# Modify default build stage in CDK Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK Pipeline to deploy a simple 3-tier web application (defined with CDK as well).

The web app is inside a CodeCommit repository and I am referencing the repo in the cdk pipeline. So far so good...

Only particularity of the web app is that is composed of 3 folders and in one there is the cdk app, so when I am running the pipeline I need to cd into the folder before running the cdk commands. The structure cannot be changed. Below the code: (the 3-tier cdk app is written in Typescript, the pipeline in Python)

```
def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        repo = codecommit.Repository.from_repository_name(self, "my-3tier-app",
            repository_name="my-3tier-app"
        )

        pipeline = CodePipeline(self, "Pipeline_test",
                        pipeline_name="my-3tier-app-pipeline",
                        synth=ShellStep("Synth",
                            input=CodePipelineSource.code_commit(repo, "main"),
                            commands=[
                                "cd subfolder",
                                "npm install",
                                "npx cdk synth"
                            ],
                            primary_output_directory="subfolder"
                        )
                    )
```

This creates a pipeline with 3 stages:

- Source
- Build
- UpdatePipeline

The **Build** stage is where I can see the commands I defined in the Synth and it succeeds.
But I am having an hard time understanding the **UpdatePipeline**.
It fails with following error: `Failed to store notices in the cache: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.cdk/cache/notices.json'`.
In the stage details, build action, there is the following Buildsepc:

```
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "npm install -g aws-cdk@2"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk -a . deploy PipelineStack --require-approval=never --verbose"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I assume it is failing because it is running the cdk deploy from the wrong directory, not the subfolder.

If my assumption is correct, then I have the following questions:

- Is this the default build action coming from the cdk?
- How can I modify this Stage so I can add an extra `cd subfolder` to it? I am getting errors with an `add_stage` to the pipeline, but maybe they are not related...
- or, how can I define the subfolder globally so I don't have to insert a lot of `cd`s

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it - you just need to adjust your `primary_output_directory` to point to the cdk.out folder: `primary_output_directory="subfolder/cdk.out"`

For reference, [the CDK Pipelines docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#synth-and-sources) mention this:

> The pipeline assumes that your ShellStep will produce a cdk.out directory in the root, containing the CDK cloud assembly. If your CDK project lives in a subdirectory, be sure to adjust the primaryOutputDirectory to match

You already did this, you only need to point it to the `cdk.out` folder and it should work.

Comment: Hey @gshpychka, thanks a lot for your input. The `primary_output_directory` is already there, without it the Build stage wasn't passing. The error I am getting is in the UploadPipeline stage

Comment: I know it's there, the key is pointing it to the `cdk.out` directory.

Comment: ah, interesting. Turns out I had a cdk.out folder probably carried out by mistake from a previous commit, most likely conflicting with the one created in the Synth. Still getting an error though, but different, meaning you were right! Just in case you can also help pointing me in the right direction, error is: `No stacks match the name(s) PipelineStack`. Thanks a lot for now!

Comment: Oh yeah, your cdk.out folder should not be committed to VCS.

Comment: its worth noting that under the commands key of your build spec you can run practically any linux command (its running AWS Linux2, a centos distro) - so you can cd to change to the cdk directory if you need to, you can do basic bash commands to explore what where so you can check your logs and see if things line up like you are expecting them to.

Comment: Thanks @lynkfox, do you know if we can edit the Buildspec commands directly from cdk pipeline code? Or the only way is to create a script as mentioned here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.pipelines/README.html#migrating-from-buildspec-yml-files

Comment: Please open a new question for that.

Comment: as the buildspec json defined in thehttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.BuildSpec.html fromObject command is just a json, you can simply edit it there. If you're used to using YAML for build specs, the commands is a Sequence Object, each string being a separate command - `"commands: ["echo first", "echo second", "echo third"]` - but i very much recommend divorcing your build spec from your cdk code if at all possible to decouple the two.